# Tell difference in Java classes between empty xml tag or nil tag

Tags: java, xml, apache-axis

I have Java classes generated with Axis2 from a wsdl. How can I tell the difference between an empty tag 
    `<tnsSchema:Name></tnsSchema:Name>`
and a nil 
    `<tnsSchema:Name xsi:nil="true"/>`
?

In the Java object if I do
`obj.getName()`
I get null in both cases.

Comment: That is parse-time event, you probably won't be able to do it after you already parsed the thing. Why do you need to tell them apart, anyway?

Comment: Because the specifics tell that are two different things: if it's just empty I have to ignore it, if it's specified "nil" I have to update the previous data to null (it means that the previous data was wrong).

Comment: what other methods available apart from getName()? do you have somethign like "getElementValue()" or similar?

Comment: Unfortunately not.